# what is static library in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to know what is static library in iphone sdk? for example I want to create common XML parser, convert it as .a extension library.If i share it to another developer, he can use it  he cannot see my code..is it possible in static library creating.I followed the [link1](http://blog.stormyprods.com/2008/11/using-static-libraries-with-iphone-sdk.html)  [link2](http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/)

Answer (score 2):

That's possible in iOS,

The library is written in C and compiles with Makefiles, Usually they are open source library.
for more read the [static library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library).

See blog post for creating static library in iOS
[Creating Static Libraries For iOS](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/)
[Universal Static Libraries in iPhone](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/04/universal-static-libraries/)